# Webpack: How to use prebuilt version of react and other libraries

Tags: reactjs, webpack

How can I use provided by React prebuilt version of a library, instead build it on every webpack's run?

Answer (score 2):

The [module.noParse](https://webpack.github.io/docs/configuration.html#module-noparse) option works for this. You can set it up like this:

```
const PATHS = {
  react: path.join(__dirname, 'node_modules/react/dist/react.min.js')
};

module.exports = {
  module: {
    noParse: [
      PATHS.react
    ]
  },
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      react: PATHS.react
    }
  }
};
```

[Source](http://survivejs.com/webpack/developing-with-webpack/optimizing-development/).